# pip --find-links option doesn't seems to be working

Tags: python, installation, pip

When attempt to install from pip

```
$ pip install Django==1.4
```

Most likely I get

> Error  while getting
>   http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.tar.gz#md5=ba8e86198a93c196015df0b363ab1109
>   (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/)

Per suggested by Jacob [in his blog](http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/), I added `--use-mirrors` but no luck.
Several comments made to this blog note that they are hosting file on their own.
So I hosted tar.gz file to say example.com/packages directory.

The command below successfully install Django 1.4

```
$ pip install https://example.com/packages/Django-1.4.tar.gz
```

The commands below doesn't seems to be working and want to find out what am I doing wrong.

```
$ pip install --find-links=https://example.com/packages/ Django==1.4
$ pip install --find-links "https://example.com/packages/" Django==1.4
$ pip install -f https://example.com/packages/ Django==1.4
```

Result in:

> Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4   Error 
>   while getting
>   http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.tar.gz#md5=ba8e86198a93c196015df0b363ab1109
>   (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/)

Not sure why it appears to be ignoring --find-links option
Apache auto-index is enabled for Packages directory hence pointing browser to https://example.com will return list of tar.gz files

Any advice would be appriciated

Comment: Must have been an issue with the download link back then. It works now.